# android magnet link data filter

Tags: android, intentfilter, magnet-uri

I want to launch an Android activity from my app when the user selects a magnet link in the browser.

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html),

> A URI is specified by separate attributes for each of its parts: 
> scheme://host:port/path or pathPrefix or pathPattern

The problem with magnet links is that they have a different pattern, like `magnet:?xt=.....`.

I tried something like this

```
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data 
        android:scheme="magnet"
        android:host="*"
    />
</intent-filter>
```

but it did not work (the activity didn't launch when I opened a magnet link in my browser). Could you help me in correctly declaring an intent filter for magnet links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work for me:

```
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data 
        android:scheme="magnet"
    />
</intent-filter>
```

Basically, I removed `android:host`